# How to overcome duplicate title tag issue on a classified website

Tags: search, seo, title

I have an Automobile classified website.If someone submit an ad for my website,the heading of the ad automatically generated from the **"make","model","registered year" and a custom text** like follows,

```
Make:-Toyota
Model:-Corolla 121
registered year:-2005
generated heading: Toyota Corolla 121 REG-2005 for sale

Make:-Nissan
Model:-Sunny N16
registered year:-2006
generated heading: Nissan Sunny N16 REG-2006 for sale
```

And I used this heading as my title tag on the individual ad page.

I have used this method for sometime.

But now those pages are listed in Google webmaster tools with duplicate title tags,because there are plenty of ads containing same make,model,and year

Does it make any sense if I use any random id along with the heading to make ad heading unique.If I do so, will it effect me to blacklist from google? OR what is the best practices to overcome this issue.
Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to add the location City/ZIP, this will give you better SEO results when searching in a specific area, also will reduce the number of duplicate title tags.

You can also add a Post ID? this will definitely make it unique for every single post

Comment: Ah I didn't noticed it.Thanks dear friend.